# Sublime Text 2: HTML tag completion doesn't work and I can't disable it

Tags: html, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have some HTML I'd like to fix:

```
<label>Name<label>
```

As you can see, this isn't closed. When I attempt to close the element, I get:

```
<label>Name</label>label>
```

Which then requires manual fixing.

How can I make Sublime autocomplete work, or disbale it? Note I already have:

```
"auto_complete": false
```

In my user preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not `auto_complete` as I know as `auto_complete` is triggered on `tab` and other key presses.

What you seek is `auto_close_tags`, setting it to false will not bother you anymore with this autocompletion, as to fixing this - I don't have such problems in ST3, so consider simply updating.